# MySQL SELECT Vehicle fitments selecting and filtering

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to achieve vehicle part product filtering, where you have `products` that belong to many different `fitments`. Such as a particular  light bulb can belong to Chevrolet, Ford, and Honda cars.

The problem I'm having is using AND and OR's just aren't working how I need them to.

Here is **pseudo** code of the results I am looking for (the tables structure and data are at the bottom):

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN fitments ON fitments.sku = products.sku

WHERE ANY fitments.make (grouped by sku) MATCHES ALL 'Ford' AND 'Chevrolet' AND 'Honda'

AND products.active = 1
AND fitments.cat_name = 'Cars'
GROUP BY products.sku
```

Ford, Chevrolet, and Honda don't exist in the same row, so I can't turn this into a WHERE clause?

`OR` doesn't work because I don't want to return results that don't match every criteria.

`AND` doesn't work because again, not every row contains all three `makes` and would return 0 rows.

The result I'm trying to achieve:

The result of the query I need help with would return one `products` row (not `fitments` because `fitments` is just the relations lookup), `BULB2` because that matches all three `make` parameters (Ford, Chevrolet, and Honda) from the possible fitments.

Two tables, Products and Fitments:

```
CREATE TABLE `fitments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `make` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_year` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_year` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30211 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sku` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63730 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `fitments` (`id`, `cat_name`, `sku`, `make`, `model`, `start_year`, `end_year`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('1', 'Cars', 'BULB1', 'Ford', 'F150', '2013', '2015', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `fitments` (`id`, `cat_name`, `sku`, `make`, `model`, `start_year`, `end_year`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2', 'Cars', 'BULB2', 'Ford', 'Explorer', '2013', '2015', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `fitments` (`id`, `cat_name`, `sku`, `make`, `model`, `start_year`, `end_year`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('3', 'Cars', 'BULB1', 'Ford', 'Mustang', '2013', '2015', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `fitments` (`id`, `cat_name`, `sku`, `make`, `model`, `start_year`, `end_year`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('4', 'Cars', 'BULB2', 'Chevrolet', 'Cobalt', '2013', '2015', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `fitments` (`id`, `cat_name`, `sku`, `make`, `model`, `start_year`, `end_year`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('5', 'Cars', 'BULB3', 'Chevrolet', 'Corvette', '2013', '2015', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `fitments` (`id`, `cat_name`, `sku`, `make`, `model`, `start_year`, `end_year`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('6', 'Cars', 'BULB2', 'Honda', 'Civic', '2013', '2015', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');


INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `sku`, `name`, `active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('1', 'BULB1', 'Generic Bulb 1', '1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `sku`, `name`, `active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2', 'BULB2', 'Generic Bulb 2', '1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `sku`, `name`, `active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('3', 'BULB3', 'Generic Bulb 3', '1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: BULB2 from the products table, because the joined sku matches all three parameters from the fitments table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer comes quite easily, if you rephrase your question: Instead of saying "is joined to Ford AND Chevrolet AND Honda", just say "is joined to Ford AND is joined to Chevrolet AND is joined to Honda":

```
SELECT
  products.*
  -- , whatever.column you need else
FROM
  products
  INNER JOIN fitments AS fitmentsFord ON products.sku=fitmentsFord.sku
  INNER JOIN fitments AS fitmentsChevrolet ON products.sku=fitmentsChevrolet.sku
  INNER JOIN fitments AS fitmentsHonda ON products.sku=fitmentsHonda.sku
WHERE
  fitmentsFord.make='Ford'
  AND fitmentsChevrolet.make='Chevrolet'
  AND fitmentsHonda.make='Honda'
  AND products.active = 1
  AND fitments.cat_name = 'Cars'
GROUP BY products.sku
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. One small concern though, and I'm definitely not an expert at JOINs-- but is this the most efficient way (performance wise) to get this if the fitments table has around 30,200 rows and the products table has around 63,700 rows?

Comment: Ask the query plan! I suspect the high selectivity of the joins will make this quite fast, assuming you have the necessary indices in place (*.sku, fitments.make)

Comment: Note that MySQL allows the use of GROUP BY in this way - typically, it even outperforms DISTINCT - but you have to be careful to avoid returning indeterminate results.

Comment: Since I suspect `sku` to be at least close to unique (while not enforced so by the DB), the `GROUP BY products.sku` does what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sku
  FROM fitments 
 WHERE make IN('Ford', 'Chevrolet', 'Honda') 
 GROUP 
    BY sku HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT make) = 3;
```

Comment: +1 for the elegance, but this might have performance issues when many fitments match one or two of the three, as the `HAVING` might involve a full table scan over a disk temptable

Comment: I think which method's faster (HAVING or JOIN) will be dependent not the size of the table so much as the sparsity of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT p.sku FROM products p
INNER JOIN 
(Select * from fitments group by make, sku) f ON f.sku = p.sku 
group by p.sku  having count(f.make)=3
```